# How can I set up a random seed inside a class header file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to set `srand(time(NULL))` inside my class which I have written in a header file. I tried putting it into constructors but it doesn't affect the `rand()`'s I call.

I also tried putting the `srand(time(NULL))` in `int main()` but that only affects the randomizers if the class is defined in the same .cpp file as the main function.

So, I was wondering if there's anyway to set the seed if I'm using a header file?

Comment: Dont use `rand`/`srand` as its a notoriously bad fit for most uses of random numbers. Use one of the c++ standard library random functions instead.

Comment: Please don't use `srand`/`rand` in C++ anymore. There are [many better facilities for pseudo random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in C++ since C++11.

Comment: That aside, `rand` only have one *global* seed, which is set by `srand`. It doesn't matter when and where you call `srand` or `rand`, it will all use the same seed irregardless of translation units.

Comment: "_tried putting the `srand(time(NULL))` in `int main()` but that only affects the randomizers if the class is defined in the same .cpp file as the main function_" - No it doesn't.

Comment: yup, I just noticed it works, I was printing the wrong value, sorry and thanks!